How does the YoloTinyNet make inference on a specific image?
I have an image weirdobject.jpg and a model that was trained through annotated image to recognize the object in that mentioned image.jpg (the annotation was done through roboflow and exported into a .ckpt file). basically this is how I use YoloTinyNet to make inferences on the input image:
class_names = ["aeroplane", "bicycle", "bird", "boat", "bottle", "bus", "car", "cat", "chair", "cow", "diningtable",
                   "dog", "horse", "motorbike", "person", "pottedplant", "sheep", "sofa", "train", "tvmonitor",
                   "small_ball"]
_common_params = {'image_size': 448, 'num_classes': len(classes_name),
                               'batch_size': 16}  # batch size 1
_net_params = {'cell_size': 7, 'boxes_per_cell': 2, 'weight_decay': 0.0005}
image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (1, 448, 448, 3))
_net =YoloTinyNet(_common_params, _net_params, test=True)
# shouldn't image contain the actual .jpg file or at this point a placeholder is sufficient?
_net .inference(image)
sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.Saver(_net.trainable_collection)
saver.restore(sess, modelFile)
src_img = cv2.imread("./weirdobject.jpg")
resized_img = cv2.resize(src_img, (448, 448))
np_img = cv2.cvtColor(resized_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
#I include the image data only at this stage (shouldn't it before that?)
np_predict = sess.run(object_predicts, feed_dict={image: np_img})

np_predict results doesn't seem to be inline with what I expect since the returned resutls include many classes of objects that aren't in the image while the true object is also included in the results.
Is this the right way to make predictions over a trained model to detect an object through a fixed image?
